# Forcing transformer models to generate only some tokens from a vocab

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, language-model

I trained a language model (encoder-decoder) to generate text. I want to restrict the generation vocab of this model to a specific vocab. How can I do that?

I found in `generate` ([model.generate](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.22.2/en/main_classes/text_generation#transformers.generation_utils.GenerationMixin.generate)) function that I can pass a parameter called `force_words_ids` where the model will be forced to generate "all" the tokens in this list. I am looking for something similar, but instead, to generate some of the list's tokens.

Answer (score 2):

As of `transformers` version `4.26.0`, you can write a custom [LogitsProcessor](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/internal/generation_utils#transformers.LogitsProcessor) and pass it as the `logits_processor` keyword argument to [model.generate](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.26.0/en/main_classes/text_generation#transformers.GenerationMixin.generate.logits_processor).  This should work in training too as long as you implement the `__call__` method of your `LogitsProcessor` as working PyTorch code.

It is also recommended to pass [`renormalize_logits=True`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.26.0/en/main_classes/text_generation#transformers.GenerationConfig.renormalize_logits) if you are generating longer output sequences with e.g. beam search and doing significant edits of the logits vector.